# A new object seems to change the fields of previous objects

Tags: java, object

I'm writing a game which contains elevators as an obstacle. An elevator spawns either left or right of the screen and has a random chance to be an ascending elevator or a descending elevator. It looks like this:

```
public class Elevator extends WorldObject {

    public static boolean ascending;

    public Elevator(int screenHeight, int xPos) {
        super(xPos, screenHeight, 0, 0);
        ascending = new Random().nextBoolean();
    }

    static public boolean isAscending(){
        return ascending;
    }

}
```

WorldObject from which it extends looks like this:

```
public class WorldObject {

    protected float posX;
    protected float posY;
    protected float velX, velY;

    public float getPosX() {
        return posX;
    }

    public void setPosX(float posX) {
        this.posX = posX;
    }

    public float getPosY() {
        return posY;
    }

    public void setPosY(float posY) {
        this.posY = posY;
    }

    public float getVelX() {
        return velX;
    }

    public void setVelX(float velX) {
        this.velX = velX;
    }

    public float getVelY() {
        return velY;
    }

    public void setVelY(float velY) {
        this.velY = velY;
    }

    public WorldObject(float posX, float posY, float velX, float velY) {
        this.posX = posX;
        this.posY = posY;
        this.velX = velX;
        this.velY = velY;
    }

}
```

Every 5 seconds an elevator will be created and added to an ArrayList of `Elevator`s like so:

```
    if (timeToElevator > 5.0f) {
        timeToElevator = 0;
        Elevator elevator = new Elevator((int) screenHeight, (int) generateElevatorXPos());
        Sprite eSprite = new Sprite(elevatorTexture);
        eSprite.setOrigin(0, 0);
        elevators.add(elevator);
        elevatorSprites.add(eSprite);
    }
```

I then check for collisions in each elevator with the player, remove it if it goes out of bounds and if neither of these happen I update the position of the elevator object:

```
public static void calculateElevatorCollisions() {
    int counter = 0;
    for (Iterator<Elevator> i = elevators.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
        Elevator item = i.next();
        if (item.getPosY() < -100) {
            //remove elevator
        } else if (..collision..) {
            //collision
        } else {
            item.setVelY(item.isAscending() ? -5 : 5);
            item.setPosY(item.getVelY() + item.getPosY());
            elevatorSprites.get(counter).setPosition(item.getPosX(),
                    item.getPosY());
            counter++;
        }
```

My issue is whenever a new `Elevator` is created all current `Elevator`s change their direction to the direction of the new `Elevator`. So suppose I have two ascending elevators being drawn, whenever my third elevator is created to be descending, the other two previously ascending elevators now ascend!

What's causing this?

Comment: A `static` field is shared by all the objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
public static boolean ascending;
       ^^^^^^
```

`static` means "This is a *class* field that is **shared** by all objects". So if you changed the field from one object, it will be noticed across *all* objects of that type.

Removing it to make `ascending` an instance field means that each instance of `Elevator` will have its *own* copy which it can modify by itself without changing other instances' copy.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
public static boolean ascending;
```

To

```
public boolean ascending;
```

When you set a variable as static it is a `class` variable, not an `instance` variable. Class variables are variables that are shared across all `instances` of an object, whereas `instance` variables are specific to that `instance` of the object.

Answer (score 0):

As I can't comment yet (rep), I want to make another note:

You are practicing encapsulation using the getter for ascending, isAscending(); however, the field you are encapsulating is `public`, making it accessible from all scopes.

It's good practice to keep encapsulated fields `private`.

Also, it seems as if everyone is only stating that the field be changed to a non-static variable; however, the method is still static, even though it is actually an instance method as well!

Resulting changes needed:

```
public static boolean ascending;
```

becomes

```
private boolean ascending;
```

...and...

```
static public boolean isAscending()
```

becomes

```
public boolean isAscending()
```